# math function as binary operations

Tags: c, binary, formula, microcontroller

I have an MP3 board attached to a ATmega microcontroller which is additionally connected to a potentiometer. The MP3 board plays MP3 data directly through its onboard speaker and therefore I am also able to set the volume of the output.

So, as you might guess, I read the value from the poti and forward it to the microcontroller. Unfortunately, the microcontroller does not increase the volume in a linear way. So, from values 0 to 128 you nearly hear nothing, and from 128 to 255 (max) the volume increases rapidly.

I found out, that the following function could solve this problem:

```
vol = 1 - (1 - x)^4
```

but x must be between 0 and 1 and the result is also between 0 and 1.

Since I am on a microcontroller, I would like to

1. transform this formula, so that I can use it with unsigned integers
2. optimize it (maybe use some cheap binary functions), because I read the poti value multiple times per second. So this function has to be calculated multiple times per second and I want to use the microcontroller for other stuff too ;-)

Maybe some of you have an idea? Would be great!

```
 uint8_t linearize_volume(uint8_t value) {
     // ideas?
     // please don't use bigger data types than uint16_t
 }
```

Comment: raising something to the fourth power is just squaring it twice. Is that too expensive? Also, how much memory do you have to precompute tables for speedups?

Comment: my problem is more that 255^4 is greater than 2^16, so I can't store it within a `uint16_t`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a decent estimate by treating the values as 8.8 fixed-point and raising to the power of four by squaring twice.

```
uint8_t linearize_volume(uint8_t value) {
    // Approximate 255 * (1 - (1 - x/255)^4)
    uint16_t x = 0xff - value;
    x = (x * x) >> 8;
    x = (x * x) >> 8;
    return 0xff - x;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can "pay" with memory for CPU cycles. If you have 256 bytes of ROM available to you, the cheapest way of computing such function would be building a lookup table.

Make a program that prints a list of 256 8-bit numbers with the values of your non-linear function. It does not matter how fast the program is, because you are going to run it only once. Copy the numbers the program prints into your C program as an array initializer, and perform the lookup instead of calculating the function.

Comment: +1: a 256 byte lookup table in ROM isn't much for the ATmega series. You could generate the LUT with more realist (complicated?) ramp functions too.

Answer (score 0):

First, be sure you're using a linear pot, not an audio-taper pot.

This is typical of audio outputs. The data is a sine wave, and therefore negative values are necessary. You can certainly convert negatives to positives for the sole purpose of accessing their power level, but you can't alter the sample without hearing a completely different sound.

Depending upon the output device, lower values may not pack enough power to energize your speaker much at all.

The "MP3 board" should include an ability to control the volume without your having to alter samples.

You state you read the pot and forward it to the micro. Aren't you reading the pot with the micro's ADC?

Comment: When I say "I read the value from the poti" I mean I use the ADC to get a value between 0 and 255.

Comment: What I can't discern is how you're getting MP3 samples into the micro. Am I being stupid? Are you asking about getting ADC samples from the pot or from the MP3 data?

Comment: Do you have an "audio pot" or a "linear pot"? There's a big difference with what the ADC will read from them. I think you're wanting a linear pot.

Comment: An audio pot will read as a taper, while a linear pot will read from 0 thru 255 uniformly. This likely explains your problem. You assume when the pot is half-way it should be reading 127, but in fact with an audio pot it might only be reading 32.